# Symfony Validator Constraints Assert Regex

Tags: php, regex, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity for which I use `Regex` and `NotBlank` to validate. I need this field to contain only English letters, without numbers. Everything works fine, but when I post Cyrillic I don't get an error. Why is that? I need only English

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *           pattern= "/^\w+/",
 *           match=   false,
 *           message= "This text cannot contain numbers"
 * )
 *
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have problem with Unicode. I could not find if the `RegEx` function does an Unicode or Ascii matching (`\u` option of `preg_match`), which might make a difference in your case (As you are certainly providing utf-8 string).

Reference:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

The second problem might be with:

```
\w+
```

Which basically means printable characters, include letters and numbers, in any encoding (If matching utf-8). In which case you might try:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: By default in `php` the regex isn't using unicode. I'm not so sure with Symfony, though. Your last suggestion should be working fine.